# How to send object via ajax with jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I try to send  WagonAvaliableResponse  object to a method via ajax .When I test this get error that   ***TypeError: WagonAvaliableResponse is not a function***

How to fix this?

```
  var WagonAvaliableResponse = {
            UniqId:'',
            checksum:'',
            FromStation:0,
            ToStation:0,
            MainUniqId:0.0,
            compartmentCapicityField:'',
            isCompartmentField:'',
            circularNumberSerialField:'',
            countingAllField:'',
            rateCodeField:0,
            airConditioningField:false,
            mediaField:false,
            timeOfArrivalField:'',
            rationCodeField:0,
            soldcountingField:0,
            ownerField: ''
        };

 $('#Continue').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault;
            var obj = new WagonAvaliableResponse();
            obj.Uniqid = $('#DepartureTrain article.show input[data=UniqId]').val();
            obj.mainuniqId = $('input[name=MainUniqId]').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Train/CheckValidSelection',
                data: obj,
                type: "POST",
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result.Message);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert(result.Message);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Delete `var obj = new WagonAvaliableResponse();`. You have already declared the object, so just use `WagonAvaliableResponse.Uniqid = ...` etc and in the ajax function -  `data: WagonAvaliableResponse,`

Answer (score 0):

You could also make it cleaner and more readable by using `$.post` instead of `$.ajax`, see below.

```
$('#Continue').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault;
  var obj = WagonAvaliableResponse;
  obj.Uniqid = $('#DepartureTrain article.showinput[data=UniqId]').val();
  obj.mainuniqId = $('input[name=MainUniqId]').val();
  $.post('/Train/CheckValidSelection', obj)
    .done(function() {
      alert( "Success" );
    })
    .fail(function() {
      alert( "error" );
    })
```